# Rescind Letter of Intent if no Conditional Job Offer is available?

Tags: job-offer, contracts

I recently signed a letter of intent (LOI) with a new contracting company. I also anticipated signing a conditional job offer (CJO) with salary, benefits, etc clearly defined. The job offer was conditional on whether or not the contracting company won the contract. In return, I agreed that the company could use my name on their proposal and I would also review their proposal.

I have just learned that due to a backlog in their system I should not expect a CJO prior to the contract being awarded.  This makes me very uncomfortable as I don't have any written guarantees that I will receive the compensation package that was verbally agreed upon by myself and the contracting company. I understand that a CJO doesn't ultimately guarantee anything and means nothing if that company doesn't win the bid. However it's better than nothing.

Should I refuse to let my name be used on their proposal?  Up to this point, I was very eager to work for this company but now I am not sure.

Comment: How does "backlog in their system" excuse them not meeting their end of your agreement? Their problem, and they need to fix it with someone personally handling/expediting it.

Comment: They said that the backlog (caused by a recent merger) has made getting CJOs out in a timely manner impossible, especially ones where they have to apply for exceptions. (The terms of my offer apparently has some exceptions in it.) The recruiter told me that he could force HR to get the exception through but isn't willing to call in that favor for a CJO when there's no guarantee they will even get the bid. I'm not sure what to believe or if this is just a part of the process.

Comment: Tricky position. My inclination is to say "if it's so exceptional it can't get done, then so is using my name on proposal," but that's easy for me to say from my armchair, because I have no "skin in the game." Easy for me to draw a hard line on this when I have nothing at stake.  Your chosen best answer is probably better than my stubborn take.

Comment: Even if you can't get a CJO, I would expect something in writing about the terms you are expecting. Although I presume you can just decline if the eventual job offer isn't what you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should I refuse to let my name be used on their proposal?

This is tough to answer.  On the one hand, will the use of your name be a **significant plus** to the company?  Could the use of your name to obtain the business in any way be **harmful to you**?

I would suggest that if there is no harm to you, let them use your name, **if** you want to work for the company.  If you don't, then you may want to consider not allowing the use of your name.

Just be sure you have you're reasoning straight, as if you rescind permission to use your name, you probably just set that bridge on fire.

Comment: Good point. Using my name will be a significant plus to their contract and would be a negative if my name was on other bids but not theirs and it will not be harmful to me. If I did rescind permission I would burn that bridge. There's a very strong possibility that I'd be picked up by the competing company so would not be left without a job. But I'm not sure I would have as good of a compensation package with the competitor. With that said, I feel like the arrangement (albeit verbal) I have with the first one is shaky and I no longer have confidence that the promised compensation will happen.

Comment: I guess I feel frustrated that I have honored my end of the agreement and they have not done their end. I also feel powerless in terms of making them honor their end. I don't want to say get me the CJO or you can't use my name as I'm not sure that will ultimately work.  Or will it?

Comment: Most likely it won't.  What are the chances of you actually seeing the submitted bid?

Comment: I won't see the final bid but could very well see a draft version of it. In addition to using my name, they have asked that I provide a technical review of the proposal. Not sure I will agree to do this anymore. In short, doesn't sound like I have much leverage, right?

Comment: @user25025 Depends on what you want the final outcome to be.  If you want the gig, then no.  Otherwise, rescind permission to use your name or credentials.  You should also think about enforcement.  In other words how can you be sure they won't use your name and credentials anway?

Comment: Thanks Mister Positive. You raise very good, logical points. Trying not to let my frustrated emotions dictate my actions.  Thanks for helping me see the situation in a different light. Still feel powerless and that I am being taken advantage of in some way or another, but the reality of my outcomes are still limited.